# Access to the properties of the successor class

Tags: typescript

Recently I started to use in their work typescript but faced with the problem. How to get around this?

```
class DisplayNode {
    parent: DisplayNode;
    childNodes: DisplayNode[];

    appendChild(child: DisplayNode) {
        child.parent = this;
        this.childNodes.push(child);
    }
}

class DisplayObject extends DisplayNode {
    displayObjProperty: string;

    update(dt: number) {
        // ... some code
        this.parent.displayObjProperty // Property 'displayObjProperty' does not exist on type 'DisplayNode'
    }
}
```

There is a way:

```
var parent: any = this.parent;
parent.displayObjProperty; // OK
```

But it's pretty ugly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast `this.parent` to `DisplayObject`:

```
var parent = <DisplayObject>this.parent;
parent.displayObjProperty; // OK
```